# Visual Studio 2012 - Collection output for listing?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, collections

So basically I'm trying to create a file manager, and I'm failing at it. I've attempted to find out and haven't found a single response on why I get a (Collection) when I'm loading file names from zip / rar files.

[image]

The code is as follows

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub modFolderButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles modFolderButton.Click
        Dim modFolder
        modFolder = modFolderText.Text
        If IO.Directory.Exists(modFolder) Then
            MsgBox("Location Successfully Set; " + modFolder, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Else
            MsgBox("Error; Invalid Location Set")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub starboundButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles starboundButton.Click
        Dim starboundFolder
        starboundFolder = starboundFolderText.Text
        If IO.Directory.Exists(starboundfolder) Then
            MsgBox("Location Successfully Set; " + starboundFolder, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Else
            MsgBox("Error; Invalid Location Set")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub listRefreshButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles listrRefreshButton.Click
        Dim modFolder
        Dim listModsDetected
        modsDetectedList.Items.Clear()
        modFolder = "C:\"
        listModsDetected = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(modFolder, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.zip")
        modsDetectedList.Items.Add("None Detected!")
        For Each fileName As String In listModsDetected
            modsDetectedList.Items.Remove("None Detected!")
            modsDetectedList.Items.Add(listModsDetected)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        modsDetectedList.Items.Add(listModsDetected)
```

You just added the collection itself to your list.
That's why it shows `(collection)`.

You probably want to add each item in the collection to your list.
That's what `For Each` gives you in `fileName`.

Comment: Thanks that seems to work however its also now displaying the entire Dir along with it, I'm looking at a snippet that removes but is there another way too remove it without adding a entire new fuction? http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=5558

Thanks Path.GetFileName() worked :D

Comment: You're looking for `Path.GetFileName()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding:

```
 modsDetectedList.Items.Add(listModsDetected)
```

Eho's ToString is its typename.

Instead use `modsDetectedList.Items.AddRange` (if it exists) or add the filename in the loop.

Comment: Attempted to use the AddRange and it gave errors about incorrect reading and I ended up using filename, just gotta find out how you remove the Dir included now. :D